# How does Doctrine handle changes to the database schema?

Tags: php, sql, database, schema, doctrine

In brief, what happens when you add a column to a table? What happens when you remove one?

In more details, suppose you have the following:

```
class User extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->hasColumn('username', 'string', 255);
        $this->hasColumn('password', 'string', 255);
    }
}
```

What happens when you add the following line to the setTableDefinition function?

```
$this->hasColumn('firstname', 'string', 255);
```

What happens when you delete the following line from the setTableDefinition function?

```
$this->hasColumn('password', 'string', 255);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to have a look at [Doctrine migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/migrations) that allows you to

> The Doctrine migration package allows
>   you to easily update your production
>   databases through a nice programmatic
>   interface. The changes are done in a
>   way so that your database is versioned
>   and you can walk backwards and
>   forwards through the database
>   versions.

That will allow you to perform changes to your database without screwing up your data.